# Class won't be found despite having been provided for initialisation at build time

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

The app runs in the JVM, this error only occurs when started  native.

The error:

```
14:51:19.539 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO  Application - Server is stopped. Releasing application resources...
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde for configuration default.key.serde: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:747)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:493)
```

The `buildArg`:

```
--initialize-at-build-time=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization,org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

The property:

```yaml
kafka.streams.default.properties.default.key.serde:  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde"
```

Any idea why the class still won't be found?

Comment: It sounds like `at.wrwks.bef.technischerplatz.streams.StringSerde` is not in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding the following to the GraalVM reflection configuration:

```json
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes",
    "queryAllDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "queryAllPublicConstructors" : true,
    "queryAllDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "queryAllPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
    "allPublicClasses" : true
  }
```